# How can i delete this gray line who's delimitating my code lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, indentation

I have a problem with the vscode editor with this grey line, [image]

It doesn't allow me to write code beyond it, once i set a semicolon the code jumps to the next line.

it's only happening with dart files

I already tried to modify configurations but it dind't work.

i hope to delete the line

Comment: what does a search in settings for `ruler` give you

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution was check the ruler in file > preferences > Configuration > ruler > edit settings.json